# Posting a JSOUP Document to login to website

Tags: android, post, cookies, ssl, jsoup

I'm posting here because I'm at my wit's end. I'm using Jsoup to post HTML data used to login. What's strange is I can enter data into the form, press Login, and get a response from the website. However, even with correct login credentials, the website is telling me that I can't login. I've got a few thoughts as to why this is:

1) HTTPS:// is before the URL i'm trying to connect to, and I've read that sometimes Jsoup has trouble with verifying SSL certificates.

2) I know for a fact that the cookies are a problem. When I use the developer options on Chrome after logging in to this website, there's a cookie there that isn't present when I print out the cookies of a Connection.Response.

3) There's a weird "Note: your data has not been lost. It will be posted after logging in securely with SSL" message when I use Jsoup to print out the resulting document after trying to login. I have no idea what that means and apparently neither does Google.

In the interest of keeping security, I've removed the actual URL I'm connecting to, but the code below should still make some sort of sense.

```
        String encodeUser = URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
        String encodePass = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

        Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://----")
                .method(Method.GET)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .execute();

        Log.v("Miles", String.valueOf(loginForm.cookies()));

        Document homeDoc = Jsoup.connect("--------")
                .cookie("T3Version", loginForm.cookie("T3Version"))
                .data("_name", encodeUser, "_pass", encodePass, "_login", "in")
                .referrer("https://web.wm.edu/studenthappenings/preview.php")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .timeout(1000)
                .post();

        Log.v("Miles", String.valueOf(loginForm.cookies()));

                    System.out.println(homeDoc.body());
            if (homeDoc.body().html().contains("Cannot perform login")){
                 Log.v("Miles", "Cannot perform login");
            }
```

It always gets into that if loop and prints the log.

Help? I'll be happy to provide more information, as you might need it when devising a solution to my stupid problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up relegating Jsoup for the sole purpose of html scrapping and reading data, using HttpClient and such to login to the website. Jsoup is awesome, but its not amazing.